# Fixing bug in MySQL COUNT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table called tbl_pet_owners:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | name   | pet      | city   | date_adopted |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  2 | jane   | dog      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  3 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-06-11   |
|  4 | jack   | cat      | Boston | 2016-07-11   |
|  5 | jim    | snake    | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  6 | jim    | goldfish | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  7 | joseph | cat      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

In a previous Stack Overflow post, I asked for help using COUNT to get the number of pets per city, BUT if an individual owns two or more pets of the same type, then those pets are counted as one. The pet types are listed in another MySQL table called tbl_pet_types:

```
+----------+---------+
| pet      | type    |
+==========+=========+
| cat      | mammal  |
+----------+---------+
| dog      | mammal  |
+----------+---------+
| snake    | reptile |
+----------+---------+
| goldfish | fish    |
+----------+---------+
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
select count(*), result.city from (
    select owners.city, types.type, owners.name
    from tbl_pet_owners owners
    left join tbl_pet_types types on owners.pet = types.pet group by owners.city, owners.name, types.type
) as result
group by result.city;
```

When I added row #3 to tbl_pet_owners:

```
+----+------+-----+--------+--------------+
| id | name | pet | city   | date_adopted |
+----+------+-----+--------+--------------+
|  3 | jane | cat | Boston | 2017-06-11   |
+----+------+-----+--------+--------------+
```

The results returned are:

```
Boston 5
NYC    1
```

They should be:

```
Boston 4
NYC    1
```

because all of jane's pets are of the same type.

It seems that jane's cats are being counted as individuals, but they should only be counted as one because the two cats are of the same type.

Any tips on how I can fix this?

Comment: Could you run the inner query on it's own and post the results?  Are you sure that all fields are identical, as they're strings you could have whitespace or capitalization in there that's confusing things.

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot that I had added a row to pet_types table mapping goldfish to sea creature, so jim's goldfish is counted twice. Hence 5 is returned for Boston instead of 4.

Comment: Well spotted, glad it's fixed! Please close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that I had added a row to pet_types table mapping goldfish to sea creature, so jim's goldfish is counted twice. Hence 5 is returned for Boston instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a SELECT DISTINCT to the inner query. 
The DISTINCT will remove the duplicate pets (i.e an owner having 2 or more if the same)

```
select count(*), result.city from (
SELECT DISTINCT owners.city, types.type, owners.name
from tbl_pet_owners owners
left join tbl_pet_types types on owners.pet = types.pet group by owners.city, owners.name, types.type ) as result group by result.city;
```